# jquery cancel sortable on specific handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I have a list to which I have applied droppable and sortable among each other.
Each list item contains a div box which gets open when click on "edit" link on the list item. There are few other list items on that div box. I want to do sorting of the div's list item among each other. But the problem I am facing is that when I am trying to sort list items the parent list item's sorting is invoked.

My research found that using "cancel" parameter helps to disable dragging. Syntax below:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ cancel: '#box' });
```

But that works perfectly for draggable. I want to achieve similar but I do not find any such parameter in case of droppable or sortable.

The visual description of the problem is linked here:
[image: http://i54.tinypic.com/678nm1.jpg]

Above I have tried to describe in a very simple manner. Actually, in my project there are many rows, panels. fields, items structure which are sortable, draggable, droppable. Very confusing though.

while I was working on the fiddle I found it working as per my need. I have linked the url here -
http://jsfiddle.net/PkRJu/9/

Looks like something else is wrong. I am working on it.
Let me know if any one can suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should be able to use the same for sortable (cancel), perhaps you can create a jsFiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: `$( ".selector" ).droppable({ disabled: true });` and `$( ".selector" ).sortable({ disabled: true });` aren't good for your case?

Comment: Can you post an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: In few mins I will upload the example on jsfiddle.

Comment: In your fiddle you must write this  {accept: '.mainlist'} otherwise it won't work. Can you tell us what's worng in your fiddle?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. It is working according to my need. In my project I am facing that problem.

Answer (score 1):

To disable sortable after you have created it you could use:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "option", "disabled", true );
```

For the droppable

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable( "option", "disabled", true );
```

If you still have problem try to post your code here and on jsfiddle.net so that we can help